# How to import name 'reflections' from 'chatbot'

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, chat, chatbot, openai-api

It doesn't work even I've imported from chatbot import Chat, reflections, multiFunctionCall. Let show me the way if you can deal with a issue

[image]

Comment: Please edit your question and add the code.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: The issue is so tough to solve . Is there someone who can solve this problem, please tell me the way.Thanks